# How to go beyond $\int\ln(f(x))dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

For my current research in economics: my result depends crucially on but one integral:
$$\int\ln(f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$$
But I know very little (practically nothing) about the shape of function $f$. How can I integrate this? Is there a general form for the solution? I can provide more background if needed.

Comment: There is no general form, more information on $f$ is needed.

Comment: Thanks. I found elsewhere that I could integrate by parts, and that I would get $\int\ln(f(x))dx=x\ln(f(x))-\int\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}dx$  Anyone confirms?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: @frencho This isn't really a reasonable question. Your question only makes sense for nonnegative $f$, so we can write $f=e^{g}$. Then your question reduces to how to integrate $$\int g(x)~\mathrm d x$$ for some real function $g$. This is too general for a question here.

Comment: Great. And the last integral in this result cannot be computed unless I know what $f(x)$ is, correct?

Comment: @frencho I don't see how you could expect to calculate any integral involving $f$ without some assumptions on $f$ (e.g., like $f$ being polynomial)

Comment: @user159517. Point taken. Indeed from the very few things I know about my function $f$ is that it cannot be negative-valued. And yes if it helps $f$ is some polynomial in $x$, but I don’t know which polynomial it is.

Comment: @frencho well, that's an assumption you need for the integral even to be defined. Maybe you could add some background to this question and explain the context.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you good folks. Very rusty with my math, so my apologies. Not to sidestep some questions, but I just dont know the answers. But let's go back to  $$\int\ln(f(x))dx=x\ln f(x)-\int\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}dx$$ for a moment because I think this is very useful for my purposes. **next question:** Consider the last integral $$\int\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}dx$$. I'm not sure what this amounts to. But I _think_ that for my purposes I can make some progress by making a variable change so that I would integrate with respect to time $t$

Comment: (I suspect something is going on with rates of change over time).

Comment: in other words, with a proper variable change, isn't $f'(x)/f(x)$ some kind of rate of growth?

Answer (score 1):

You could try integrating by parts:

$$\int ln(f(x))dx=\int 1\cdot ln(f(x))dx= xln(f(x))-\int x\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx$$

You can then continue depending on what you know about the function f(x).

Comment: Awesome. Confirmed twice! But I know next to nothing regarding $f$, however whatever math I have left in me senses that something is going on with the last integral, maybe some kind of rate of change over time if we do a variable change from integrating wrt $x$ to integrating wrt $t$ (time). Is there a hint of truth in this intuition?